# Why I'm not getting the output I expect unless I put a breakpoint?

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, python-requests

I'm having an issue with a function, I'm supposed to get a `JSON` that I get only when I put a breakpoint on line 8, but when I remove the breakpoint and return/print `decodedInfo` I get a blank list, here is my code:

```
1  from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
2  import requests
3
4  @app.route('/urlinfo', methods=['POST'])
5  def foo():
6      urlId = request.json.get('urlId')
7      requestUrl = 'https://127.0.0.1/' + urlId + '/bar'
8      urlInfo = requests.get(requestUrl)
9      decodedInfo = urlInfo.content.decode()
10     print(decodedInfo)
11     return decodedInfo
```

Comment: How do you call the method ? Is the code all good indented ? First use directly `urlInfo.text` and if the server has set-up the good content-type header, you can do `urlInfo.json()` and you directly object a python objetc, not a string

Comment: Sorry, I missed a line, I use it with postman using flask, everything is intended and I use atom's autopep8 extension to be sure, using .text or .json() gives the same result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding a timer before line 8 solved the issue.